# Creating a 2D array for JQuery

Tags: javascript

I have an array that i want to include when creating a 2D array:

```
var v=[22,34,13,13];
var dataV = new Array();

for(var i=0; i<4; i++) 
  dataV = [i,v[i]];

console.log(dataV);
```

Output should be:

```
[[0, 22],
[1, 34],
[2, 13],
[3, 13]]
```

I am using this array with JQuery charts. However the chart seems to only show the last value (13).
Anyone know if i am not converting my array properly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is Chrome's JavaScript console lazy about evaluating arrays?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057440/is-chromes-javascript-console-lazy-about-evaluating-arrays)

Answer (score 2):

You need to add it to `dataV`. Currently you're *overwriting* `dataV`.

You can use `.push()`:

```
dataV.push([i,v[i]]);
```

or assign by index:

```
dataV[i] = [i,v[i]];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var v=[22,34,13,13];
var dataV = new Array();
for(var i=0; i<4; i++) {
  dataV.push([i,v[i]]);
  console.log(dataV);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var v=[22,34,13,13];
var dataV = new Array();
for(var i=0; i<4; i++) 
  dataV[dataV.length] = [i,v[i]];
console.log(dataV);
```

Comment: user1689607 @Tom Very helpful guys thanks you a span! Push seems to work perfectly.